# How do I fix this error NameError: uninitialized constant AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, web-deployment, rails-activestorage, aws-sdk-ruby

So I got this error: NameError: uninitialized constant which StackOverflow says means that it is unintentionally upgrading, but that cannot be, because my version is the highest, I have in the gem file: gem "aws-sdk-s3", require: false

Could it have to do with the initializer file?
This is where in the build log it went wrong:

```
Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       NameError: uninitialized constant AWS
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:80:in `block in load_missing_constant'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:9:in `without_bootsnap_cache'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:80:in `rescue in load_missing_constant'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:59:in `load_missing_constant'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/config/initializers/aws.rb:1:in `<main>'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `load'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `load'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:666:in `block in load_config_initializer'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:182:in `instrument'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:665:in `load_config_initializer'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:625:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:624:in `each'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:624:in `block in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:339:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:523:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       
       Caused by:
       NameError: uninitialized constant AWS
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:61:in `block in load_missing_constant'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:17:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:60:in `load_missing_constant'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/config/initializers/aws.rb:1:in `<main>'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `load'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `load'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:666:in `block in load_config_initializer'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:182:in `instrument'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:665:in `load_config_initializer'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:625:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:624:in `each'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:624:in `block in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:339:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:523:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_381cfb05_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

This is the aws.rb file:

```
AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
    :access_key_id   => ENV['S3_KEY:'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET']
   )
```

This is on the Heroku side:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0PY1.png)

I'm not allowed to embed images yet so there's the link only.

Okay, I changed the aws.rb file to this:

```
require 'aws-sdk'
AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
    :access_key_id   => ENV['S3_KEY:'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET']
   )
```

And got this:

```
 Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       LoadError: cannot load such file -- aws-sdk
```

I changed the AWS gem to: gem 'aws-sdk'

and got this output from the build log failure instead:

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       NameError: uninitialized constant AWS
```

This is part of my storage.yml file:

```
# Use rails credentials:edit to set the AWS secrets (as aws:access_key_id|secret_access_key)
amazon:
   service: S3
   #access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
  # secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
   region: us-east-1
   bucket: agrifood.bucket
```

After commenting out the aws.rb intializer file and changing the storage.yml to the below:

```
# Use rails credentials:edit to set the AWS secrets (as aws:access_key_id|secret_access_key)
amazon:
   service: S3
   #access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
   #access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id  => ENV['S3_KEY:']) %>
   access_key_id: ENV['S3_KEY:'])
   secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET'])
   #secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET']) %>
   #secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
   #region: us-east-1
   region: eu-west-1
   bucket: agrifood.bucket
```

And  adding the Active Storage build pack, I got this:

```
###### WARNING:
       We detected that some binary dependencies required to
       use all the preview features of Active Storage are not
       present on this system.
       
       For more information please see:
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku
```

Most recently I changed the storage.yml to this:

```
amazon:
   service: S3
   #access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
   #access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id  => ENV['S3_KEY:']) %>
   access_key_id: ENV['S3_KEY:'])
   secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET'])
   #secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET']) %>
   #secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
   #region: us-east-1
   #region: eu-west-1
   region: ENV['AWS_BUCKET_REGION'])
   bucket: agrifood.bucket
'''
Which still gave me this:
```

WARNING:
Detecting rails configuration failed
set HEROKU_DEBUG_RAILS_RUNNER=1 to debug

WARNING:

```
   We detected that some binary dependencies required to
   use all the preview features of Active Storage are not
   present on this system.
```

```
I then changed it to this:
```

Aws.config.update({
region: 'eu-west-1',
credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['S3_KEY:'], ENV['S3_SECRET']),
})

S3_BUCKET = Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET'])

```
As per the advice to changed AWS to Aws I did what is just above, however, that didn't fix it.
```

Comment: Have you `require`d the aws sdk before any usages of AWS (that can be done in an initializer)? Have you tried to remove `require: false` from the gemfile?

Comment: @MahmoudSayed Which should I do first?

Comment: I'm not sure but I see in [document](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby#configuration-options) it uses `Aws` constant instead

Comment: @FintanMoloney Try to remove `require: false` from Gemfile and re-run `bundle install`.

Answer (score 0):

try to make `bundle install`, it it does not help, share the file `config/initializers/aws.rb` with us, to understand the problem better. The error because you do not AWS in your application

Comment: Added the aws.rb file now. @bigidigi89

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by changing the Gem to:

```
 gem 'aws-sdk-v1'
```

and remove: require 'aws-sdk'.

This worked for me.
Thanks